# !DOCTYPES the document type definition in more detail

Tags: xhtml-1.0-strict

I am researching this in detail and just need more specific answers on the various parts of a !DOCTYPE.

In particular I would like a thorough break down of the parts of a !DOCTYPE that is strict.

I understand that there are various !DOCTYPES and I would like to know what every part of the declaration means as it is broken down into its various parts and this will help me move on with my research.

!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  (let's start here)

I understand that a doctype is the first thing you should see declared at the top of an html page in the code and that this tells the browser how to display your code.

Then we come to html:
Explaining that this is a hyper text mark-up language being used

'PUBLIC' what is this referring to exactly could you help me with this?